# Scroll transition to the second section on mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to reproduce a smooth scroll page transition between the first section (fixed element with height 100vh) and the second (relative element with height auto).

The transition should works like fullpage.js (pretty much), but only between the first and the second section, as in the second section I have a longer content.

On document load my html looks like that:

1. first section ==> fixed; top: 0; height: 100vh;
2. second section ==> relative; transform: translateY(100%); height: auto;

Then I bind the mouse wheel and I add some classes to hide and show the sections:

1. first section ==> fixed; visibility: hidden;  transform: scale(.5);
2. second section ==> relative; transform: translateY(0%);

To be honest I’m not sure that’s the right way to do this effect and, furthermore, I do not understand how to come back to the initial arrangement when I scroll up to the top.

I found the transition in this website [www.linealight.com](http://www.linealight.com)

Please, could someone help me?

Grazie!

Here's my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nik1987/wf4L2t1a/

```js
// detect mouse direction
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
  if (window.removeEventListener)
    window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
  window.onwheel = null; 
  window.ontouchmove = null;  
  document.onkeydown = null;

  $('#one').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  });

}
// ***


$(function() {
  var scrollTopWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
  var scrollTopTwo = $('#two').scrollTop();

  disableScroll();
  $('body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      // scroll UP
      $('#two').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        $('#two').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
          if( ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) ) {
            $('#one').removeClass('push-out');
            $('#two').removeClass('push-in');
            setTimeout(disableScroll, 2000);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    else{
      // scroll DOWN
      $('#one').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('push-out');
        $('#two').addClass('push-in');
        $(window).scrollTop(0, 1000);
        setTimeout(enableScroll, 2000);
      });
    }

  });

});
```